# Could today's Windows update have caused boot problems?

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, windows-update

I have a 64 bit box that is dual boot Windows 7 64-bit and Ubuntu.
I booted into Windows today and saw the 'updates ready' sign on the shutdown button so I clicked to let it install.  It took a while to install 2 updates. 
Then I rebooted, but now it doesn't get past the motherboard splash screen.  So I don't even get the disks found messages or let alone the prompt to choose Windows or Linux. 
Could this be caused by the updates? Seems weird for a Windows patch to have consequences beyond the Windows OS,  but it seems unlikely to be a coincidence

Comment: It might be coincidental. Hard drives most often fail on start-up.

Comment: Tried a boot disk? My other suggestion is try shutting down, removing all power sources (including removing the BIOS battery, if you don't mind), and see if you can boot again. Unless you did a BIOS update (which Windows Update does not supply), you can't really prevent booting for all operating systems.

Comment: Remember to set date and time in bios after you remove the cmos battery, Before Windows loads.

Answer (score 0):

I left if for an hour, and now it booted again. No Idea what happened exactly.

Comment: We call that a bios fart.....